# What's the name of this setting for the Angelus?

Tags: liturgy, hymns, liturgy-of-the-hours, hail-mary

Here's a YouTube video of an English-language setting of the Angelus that appears to be popular among Anglo-Catholics (it's used at Pusey House)...I've not been able to find the name of the hymn tune.

Link: [The Angelus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJx7VTDiy4M)

And here's the specific wording of this variant:

> The angel  of the Lord brought tidings to Mary: And she conceived by
> the Holy Ghost.
>
> Hail Mary, full of grace, the Lord is with thee;
> blessed art thou among women, and blessed is the fruit of thy womb
> Jesus. Holy Mary, Mother of God, pray for us sinners, now, and at the
> hour of our death. Amen.
>
> Behold the handmaid of the Lord: Be it unto me according to thy word.
>
> Hail Mary, &c.
>
> And the Word was made flesh: And dwelt among us.
>
> Hail Mary, &c.
>
> Pray for us, holy Mother of God. That we may be made worthy
> of the promises of Christ. Pour forth, we beseech thee, O Lord, thy
> grace into our hearts; that as we have known the incarnation of thy
> Son Jesus Christ by the message of an angel, so by his cross and
> passion we may be brought to the glory of his resurrection. Through
> Jesus Christ our Lord. Amen.

Answer (score 3):

It may not have a name. The melodies of the tune are rather standard chant formulae used in Anglo Catholic circles, but not necessarily specifically for the Angelus, so it may not be a formal, named hymn tune, or if it is a named tune, it may be in very limited distribution. You might try to contact the organist of the congregtion mentioned in the comments on the video, if all else fails.

Comment: I think I might have a chat with the Pusey House sub-organist. I figure my source of last resort could be the RSCM. I think I will do that and then use the 'Answer Your Question' feature, if that's OK.

Comment: The intonation and response to the opening versicle is the common "sol mi fa" formula of an invocation. The following two versicles use the formula "sol mi sol". The melody for the "Ave Maria" responsory is not one I recognize. It may be from a Latin source, perhaps Paris, or a book of melodies from D'Anjer. I don't recognize it, and frankly don't expect it to be in RSCM materials, at least not current ones. The first place I'd look is in G. R. Woodward's Songs of Zion, published in 1904. Unfortunately my copy is in storage, and I can't say whether it is in fact there, or not.